# Fluent NHibernate Insert Null FK

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a table mapping with nullable FK constraint. In my fluent mapping I am doing something like so:

```
public enum PlayerPosition
{
        None = 0,
        Forward = 1
//etc
}
```

Entity

```
public virtual PlayerPosition? Position { get; set; }

Map(x => x.Position).Column("PlayerPositionId").CustomType< PlayerPosition>();
```

What I would like to happen is when PlayerPosition is set to "None" Nhibernate will insert null. I am not sure how to make that happen.

Comment: So you want to have *two* representations of `null`, either `PlayerPosition.None` or an actual `null` value? Why? What does a stored `null` value mean in reverse, then, does it mean that the `PlayerPosition` property should be initialized to `None` or `null`? Seems like the simpler/cleaner solution would be to align your enum to what's actually in the database, and handle any oddball mappings in the mapping layer (that is, the mapping layer between NHibernate entities and domain or presentation model). I also don't actually see an FK (`References`) here - just a property mapping?

Comment: I am not adding it as a reference I am just mapping it. Yes I would like to map PlayerPosition.None to map to a null reference in the database. This is not a question about DB design or alignment it is a question about how to mapping a problem. Some things are out of my control.

Answer (score 1):

i would go for IUserType:

```
public virtual PlayerPosition Position { get; set; }

Map(x => x.Position).Column("PlayerPositionId").CustomType<PlayerPositionUserType>();

class PlayerPositionUserType : IUserType
{

    public object NullSafeGet(IDBReader reader, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        int? positionvalue = NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeGet(reader, names[0]);
        return (positionvalue.HasValue) ? (PlayerPosition)positionvalue : PlayerPosition.None;
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDBCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        var position = (PlayerPosition)value;
        if (position == PlayerPosition.None)
            NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index);
        else
            NHibernateUtil.Int32.NullSafeSet(cmd, (int)position, index);
    }

    public Type ReturnType
    {
        get { return typeof(PlayerPosition); }
    }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get { return new [] { SqlTypeFactory.Int32 } }
    }
}
```